# Factorize RSA with quadratic factor

Tags: number-theory, factoring, cryptography

In normal RSA we have $n = pq $ with $p$ and $q$ being prime numbers

Suppose now we have $n = r^2 pq t $ with $r,p,q,t$ being prime.

Is it possible to factorize with the $r^2$ more easily?

For example what would be the upper bound for testing

$gcd(r^2,n)$ ,  for all $r$ between 2 and the upper bound?

Comment: For the same size number one of the prime factors would need to be under the sqrt of the usual case ( and therefore under the fourth root of $n$)

Comment: Simply having more factors would make it easier/faster to factor, since for $n = r^2pqt$ you'd only have to search up to $n^{1/5}$ to find a factor. This is not necessarily the factor $r$ though. If your goal is to be guaranteed to find $r$, the lowest possible values for $p, q, t$ are $2, 3, 5$ (or all equal to $2$, if you don't mean for them to be distinct). Thus $r$ is not larger than $\sqrt{n/30}$ (or $\sqrt{n/8}$).

Comment: There is still no efficient way to find the factors if they are all huge. Determining whether a number is squarefree is not significantly easier than factoring it.